# Why was the "CEO powers" question closed?

Tags: discussion

I opened a question about a CEO role. One comment mentioned this is case-by-case, but I didn't even know there was so much variance for a CEO position. Also, while I had questions closed in the past, this is the fastest closing process so far.
So... does the CEO role not exist in reality? If a role is completely undefined, then it's not a role at all, right?

Edit:
I just saw this:
[Which kind of motivation software companies expects from applicant?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/160461/which-kind-of-motivation-software-companies-expects-from-applicant)

I genuinely don't understand how my question was "very company-specific" while the question above is not.

Comment: It seems like a pretty straightforward example of a company-specific question. What is within the CEO's purview, what's with other elements of the C-suite and how much control the board has are all aspects that can vary tremendously by company. Even if there was a general answer, that wouldn't help you in your particular situation since your motivation is presumably to find out what *your* powers would be in the CEO role you've been offered. A better question would be about how to establish the "powers" you'll have in a negotiation with the owners/board.

Comment: @Lilienthal Obviously the community does not agree with me, but _"What is within the CEO's purview ... can vary tremendously by company ... [you need to] establish the "powers" you'll have in a negotiation with the owners/board"_ sounds like the answer the OP didn't know and was looking for, which may help others in a similar situation in the future.

Comment: @PlayerOne Fair point. Usually comments are left on the main post explaining the reason for closure. Perhaps people assumed it was relatively obvious (for someone at the experience level to become CEO).

Comment: Edited asking about https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/160461/which-kind-of-motivation-software-companies-expects-from-applicant

Answer (score 4):

> I genuinely don't understand how my question was "very
> company-specific" while the question above is not.

You were asking about one specific job at one specific company.

You wrote: "I am being offered a job as a CEO of a small company. I am wondering: what power would I actually have?"

There's no way anyone can answer what your power at that particular company would be.

If instead you had asked more about "What kind of power does a CEO at a small startup company usually have?" you might have gotten some on-target answers. Even then, only extremely general answers would be likely, since there's no one rule or standard regarding CEO powers.

Obviously, the only way for you to have any idea what your actual role would entail would be to ask those who would give you the role - in this case, the investors. That is no different than questions about any job at any company - what you do is determined within the company.

The question you linked to is far more general. And it got generalized answers.

If you still care about your question, try editing it to be a lot more generalized and see if you can get some reopen votes.

Comment: Thanks. I tried to do this here:
https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/182246/for-any-ceo-role-which-core-responsibilities-are-never-delegated-independently

this new question got a close vote in less than 60 seconds, because it doesn't follow "community guidelines"

Comment: @Monoandale - don't stress over the "I was the first to cast a close vote" crew.

Comment: @Monoandale - have you tried to find answers to your question via a Google search? For example: https://corporatefinanceinstitute.com/resources/careers/jobs/what-is-a-ceo-chief-executive-officer/

Answer (score 1):

Please see my post here:

[PSA: Recognize effort before voting to close (or forcing close)](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7035/psa-recognize-effort-before-voting-to-close-or-forcing-close)

Fundamentally it's much easy to click the close button, rather than thinking about what the "real" question the OP should be asking, and answer that.

It obvious there are a lot of questions where a simple suggested reframing of the question, either in the question itself, or in an answer, would have given a lot of benefit to the OP.